# How to reference ArrayList into a HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have an ArrayList of getCourses and a HashMap for a ComboBox below:

```
public class QueryCourses {    
public static ArrayList<Courses> getCourses() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String queryCourses = "SELECT course_id, course_title FROM tblcourses";
    Connection conn = DbConnection.ConnectDB();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryCourses);
    ArrayList<Courses> courseList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {            
        Courses crse = new Courses(rs.getInt("course_id"), rs.getString("course_title"));
        courseList.add(crse);
    }
    return courseList;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap(){
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    final ComboBox<Courses> cmbCourse = new ComboBox(courseList.getItems());
    Connection conn = DbConnection.ConnectDB();

    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "SELECT `course_id`, `course_title` FROM `tblcourses`";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
        Courses crse;

        while (rs.next()) {                
            crse = new Courses(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
            cmbCourse.addItem(crse);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return map;
}
```

}

I would like to reference the ArrayList onto the HashMap of a ComboBox in which has the id of a course and its title but I do not know which to reference the getCourses or the courseList.  Either of which gives me an error, am I missing something or what? This will then output onto the ComboBox the title and can return the key for database insertion.

Comment: getCourses will return an ArrayList and from there you can get the object then its property. How did you did it so far?

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList cannot be referenced to HashMap. You need to iterate through the arraylist (from getCourses() ) and individually set each element to the map.

Something like :

```
for(Course crse : getCourses()){
  map.put(crse.getId(),crse.getTitle() );
}
```